# Getting admin password while copy file using shutil.copy?

Tags: python, file-permissions

I m using shutil.copy from python to copy a list of files. But when i copy the files to /usr/lib/ location, i m getting permission denied as i need to be an administrator to do that.

So How could i copy files with admin permission or 
how could i get the admin password from the user to copy the files?

Ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Doesn't belong on superuser; this is how to write a copy command with Python (scripting language).

Answer (score 4):

Make the user run the script as an administrator:

```
sudo python-script.py
```

Unix already has authentication and password management. You don't need to write your own, and there will doubtless be security bugs if you try.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what **katrielalex** said: you can make the script run itself via `sudo` if you want. Here's a proof of concept:

```
import sys, os, subprocess

def do_root_stuff():
    print('Trying to list /root:')
    for filename in os.listdir('/root'):
        print(filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Running as UID %d:' % os.geteuid())

    if os.geteuid() == 0:
        do_root_stuff()
    else:
        subprocess.check_call(['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start your program with a user that is allowed to write there. For example login to root first (`su`) or run the script with `sudo myscript.py`.

Answer (score 0):

I came her looking for an alternative way of doing things.
A quick and dirty hack I use, because I don't want my whole script to run as root:

```
try:
    shutil.os.remove(file1)
except PermissionError:
    shutil.os.system('sudo chown $USER "{}"'.format(file1))  
    # try again
    try:
        shutil.os.remove(file1)
    except:
        print('Giving up on'.format(file1))
```

Which is probably not completely error-prone, but they work for the quick scripts I hack together

Oops, I saw you were asking for copy permissions.
But you could apply the same logic

```
try:
   shutil.os.copy(file1,destination)
except PermissionError:
   shutil.os.system('sudo cp "{}" "{}"'.format(file1,destination))
```