# return code of 256 from python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, raspbian

This is a reposted question from raspberrypi.stackexchange.com. While I am trying to get something to work on python on the raspberry pi, since it doesn't involve any pi-specific things, it was suggested by someone I post here instead. Original post is [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9894/return-code-of-256-from-python).

---

I am trying to make a web ui to change the date in the rapsberry pi, but I keep getting a return code of 256.

Currently what I have goes like this:

web page -> submits an ajax request to a python script
python checks what type of command (a time/date command in this case) and pieces together a string looking like:

```
sudo date --set="20130901 20:10"
```

and stores it in a variable `commandString`. Then python goes:

```
os.system(commandString)
```

and the return value is passed all the way up to the web ui where it is printed out.

I also currently return the `commandString` value to the web ui too to verify it and it looks okay.

The problem is that every time I test, I keep getting back 256 as the error return code. The date on the raspberry pi of course doesn't change as I manually check it before and after.

However, if I manually go in to python on the raspberry pi and try:

```
commandString = 'sudo date --set="20130901 20:10"'
os.system(commandString)
```

It works with no issues. If I try it without `sudo` then I get a return value of 256 as well, so I thought maybe it was a permissions issue with my original script. I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806897/what-is-the-best-practices-for-checking-if-the-user-of-a-python-script-has-root) to check my script's permissions and it seems to be okay? (`os.geteuid()` is 0)

If it matters, I am using lighttpd and fastcgi to run python from a web ui. My lighttpd config is currently:

```
fastcgi.server = (
    ".py" => (
    "python-fcgi" => (
    "socket" => "/tmp/fastcgi.python.socket",
    "bin-path" => "/var/www/command.py",
    "check-local" => "disable",
    "max-procs" => 1)
    )
)
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

---

On the original post, it was also suggested I try something like:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S date --set="20130829 02:02
```

While it's probably not a good idea to put in my root password like that, I tried it and got the same result: it works when doing in the terminal/shell and within the python interpreter, but not via the web ui to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** or maybe just use `/usr/bin/sudo /bin/date ...` to make sure the commands are found.

Try this:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('sudo -S date --set ...', shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(input='<your password>')
```

This is a more proper way of launching a subprocess (via the shell), and sending it some input.

If you also need to read the output of the process, then for example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('sudo -S date --set ...', shell=True,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(input='<your password>')
print "\n".join("out: " + x for x in out.split('\n'))
print "\n".join("err: " + x for x in err.split('\n'))
```

...or just take the contents of `out` and/or `err` and parse them.

Comment: hello, trying the first method (don't really need the output for this part) now yields an error code of 1. From searching, I think this means "Operation not permitted" ?

Comment: ok. sorry to post another comment right away, but this is really weird. Just for fun, I tried it without sudo (just date --set=...) and changed p.communicate to p.wait. Interestingly I get my return code of 0 and it seems to work. O.o Any ideas on why adding sudo (with and without password) gives a return code of 1, while not having it lets it go through? (Within the script os.geteuid() was always 0). I think I need to take a break, shutdown my pi then pick it back up later verify as this feels very random on why it's working. =_=

Comment: yup... this seems to work now. using subprocess instead of os.system and not using 'sudo' with my command.

Comment: actually that `sudo` thing puzzled me as well—how did you end up getting by without it?

Comment: I'm not sure. Originally I thought to use os.system("date --set=...") as it said my script was ran under pi/root. This works in the python shell, but in a script it returns 256. Figuring it was a permission issue (sources say error codes are * by 256), I added "sudo" and so forth. In the end, I used your suggestion of using python's subprocess but without sudo, going: p = subprocess.Popen("date --set=...", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE); p.wait(); return p.returncode; I didn't change anything config/permission-wise. I hope this is supposed to be how it works and not just working by chance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the environment whether `sudo` and `date`(or any other command you want to execute) can actually be found on the search path.

You can also use absolute paths to `sudo` and other commands, e.g. `/usr/sbin/sudo`