# Can my Python script distinguish between if it was run as root or if it was run through sudo?

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-2.x, sudo, rhel

```
[root@hostname ~]# python script.py                  # allow this

[user@hostname ~]$ sudo python script.py             # deny this
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo -E python script.py          # deny this
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo PATH=$PATH python script.py  # deny this
[user@hostname ~]$ python script.py                  # kindly refuse this
```

**I'm trying to achieve the behavior above.** Read further if you care why or if the example isn't sufficient enough. Sorry for the sharp tongue, but most of my Stack Exchange questions get hostile questions back instead of answers.

This question arises from requiring an admin to run my script, but the nature of the script requires `root`'s environment variables (and not `sudo`'s).

I've given this some thorough research... [below is from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2806923/7851115)

```
if os.geteuid() == 0:
    pass  # sufficient to determine if elevated privileges
```

But then I started needing to access `PATH` inside of my script. I noticed that

```
sudo -E env | grep PATH; env | grep PATH
```

prints different `PATH` values. I found it was because of the security policy on `PATH`. I also found [the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8633575/7851115) to `PATH` is `sudo PATH=$PATH ...`

However, it's not the only policy protected environment variable, and at that point, why push this enumeration of environment variables on the script user? It seems that requiring `root` explicitly is the best approach, and just warn the admin to use `root` explicitly from within the script otherwise.

Is there such a way to distinguish between `root` and `sudo` with Python?

Comment: The root prompt should end with "#".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams fixed, silly me. Thank you

Comment: Which OS/version? There are some nuances between *NIX flavors.

Comment: Multiple versions of RHEL.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Doesn't have to. The root prompt ends with whatever the PROMPT variable tells it to end with.

Comment: "but the nature of the script requires root's environment variables (and not sudo's)" - then check the environment variables you need?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875055/3757232) help?

Comment: Why not just check the username?

Comment: I would do something stupid, e.g. check value of HOME variable. Combined with explicit warning in docs that sudo shouldn't be used

Comment: @JaredSmith Using `username = commands.getoutput("echo $(whoami)")` as `sudo` returns `root`

Comment: `sudo PATH=$PATH ...` doesn't use root's PATH, anyway; it uses your own PATH. Do you want root's environment variables or your own environment variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the reasons discussed to not pursue this solution, I actually did find it for others wondering if [it's possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11471/233770).

```
[user@hostname ~]$ sudo python
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["SUDO_UID"]  # UID of user running sudo
'uid'
```

And when logged in as root...

```
[root@hostname ~]# python
>>> import os
>>> try:
...     uid = os.environ["SUDO_UID"]
        raise AssertionError("Ran with sudo")
... except KeyError, e:
...     ...  # SUDO_UID, SUDO_USER, etc. not set without sudo
```

---

I also [found](https://www.systutorials.com/241602/how-to-get-another-users-path-in-bash-on-linux/) a way to access `root`'s `PATH` just running with `sudo`.

```
path = os.popen("su - -c env | grep ^PATH= | cut -d'=' -f2-").read().strip()
```

I think I like this solution better than relying on how my script is ran.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to get "hostile questions" because the premise of your issue doesn't make much sense. In general if a command can be run as the root user via `sudo` then it should not matter whether it was run via `sudo` (or `runas`, etc.) or by some other mechanism that has the UID set to root such as an interactive login as the root user. You should not require running a program to be predicated on an interactive login as the root user account rather than via a setuid program like `sudo` or your program if it were setuid root.

A cheap and dirty solution is to ensure the interactive root login sets a unique env var that is unlikely to be set when your program is run via `sudo`. That is, however, obviously easy to spoof so if you're doing this for security then that approach is not acceptable.

Comment: Thank you. I realize now that what I'm asking for is probably not the proper solution, but you and others have helped me better understand what `sudo` really does. Nevertheless, I think other people could have this question in the future too and maybe could learn from my mistake as I did. I'm choosing @Andriy's suggestion to document it and leave it be. However, because this is predicated on security, it's somewhat irksome that I can't verify that I'm really checking through `root`'s `PATH` directories.

Answer (score -4):

Use the subprocess module to run commands and check the output:

```
from subprocess import check_output
```

```
uid = check_output(['bash', '-c', 'echo $UID']).decode().strip()
if uid != '0':
    sys.exit()  # or return
```

or

```
user = check_output(['whoami']).decode().strip()
if user != 'root':
    sys.exit()  # or return
```

It appears that aside from checking $PATH, root and sudo are indistinguishable.

Comment: Just `getpass.getuser()`.