# Python Check Permissions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, sudo

**Please note, I'm NOT asking about the user running it but rather did he run it as sudo command or not**

I have a python script, which I want to obligate the user to run it like this:

```
sudo python3 script.py
```

and not like this:

```
python3 script.py
```

How can I do verify in run time if it was run correctly or not (if so end program using sys.exit())?

Comment: Your question seems to missing something after “like this:”.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way for checking if the user of a script has root-like privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806897/what-is-the-best-way-for-checking-if-the-user-of-a-script-has-root-like-privileg)

Comment: @quassy thanks :)

Comment: @Brian not exactly, I'm not asking about the user running it but rather did he run it as sudo or not

Comment: @daniel `sudo` works by changing the effective user. If you just want to check if the user has `sudo`-level permissions and not some more specific subset, checking the user is the defacto way. See also [Does `sudo` work in terms of changing the effective user and group IDs of a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/333236) and [How do the internals of sudo work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80344)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this topic:
[What is the best way for checking if the user of a script has root-like privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806897/what-is-the-best-way-for-checking-if-the-user-of-a-script-has-root-like-privileg)

It has a bunch of solutions that you might find helpful.

Comment: Please Note, I'm not asking about the user running it but rather did he run it as sudo or not